# PDF Documents Not Printing from Server-Side ASP.NET App

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, pdf, printing, windows-server-2008-r2

### Preface:

We are developing a suite of applications (mobile and desktop) which leverage our restapi maintained by an ASP.NET application running on a *Windows Server 2008 R2* server. One of the features we are integrating on the back-end is a printing function which pulls a pdf from our SSRS service and then prints to a network printer.

There are many threads on printing silently and leveraging different products and most of these solutions have worked on my local machine (*Windows 10*); however, when moving our code up to our server we are finding that parts of the code execute but the document never reaches the printer.

### Our code:

```
private async Task<bool> Print(string filename, string printer)
{
    var processFilename = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine
    .OpenSubKey("Software")
    .OpenSubKey("Microsoft")
    .OpenSubKey("Windows")
    .OpenSubKey("CurrentVersion")
    .OpenSubKey("App Paths")
    .OpenSubKey("AcroRd32.exe")
    .GetValue(String.Empty).ToString();

    var fileInfo = new FileInfo(processFilename);

    var workingDirectory = fileInfo.Directory.FullName;

    Process process = new Process();
    process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            
    process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
    {
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        FileName = processFilename,
        UseShellExecute = true,
        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
        ErrorDialog = false,
        Arguments = $"/t {filename} \"{printer}\"",
        WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory
     };

            try
            {
                var processStarted = process.Start();
                if (processStarted)
                {
                    LogHelper.WriteLog($"Print Process Started. Process: {process.ProcessName}");
                }
                else
                {
                    process.Close();
                    LogHelper.WriteLog($"Print Process Not Started.");
                    throw new Exception("Error in PrintHelper.Print(): Print Process did not start.");
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Began Printing! (Test)");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                LogHelper.WriteLog($"Error in PrintHelper.Print(): {e.Message}");

                throw e;
            }
            finally
            {
                process.Close();
                Console.WriteLine("Finished Printing! (Test)");
            }

            LogHelper.WriteLog("Ending PrintHelper.Print().");

            return true;
}
```

### We have tried:

1. Setting filename to the .PDF to print and using the Verbs "Print" and "PrintTo"
2. Setting UseShellExecute to both True and False
3. Passing in Network credentials and LoadUserProfile as True
4. Setting the ASP.NET AppPool that runs our app to be LocalSystem
5. Running the same print command via command line (while logged in as a different user) and the document prints.

### Notable Findings:

1. Leveraging Adobe Acrobat Reader DC, we see it launch on the server with Username blank, instead of SYSTEM or anything, though no document is sent to the printer. When running the code locally, the Adobe Acrobat Reader DC launches with username as the user logged in, and the document is printed successfully.
2. PDF document exists and this has been verified both locally and on server.
3. No exceptions are thrown, Adobe Acrobat Reader DC opens successfully, just no document is sent to the printer on the server.

As an additional rationale on our intent: we are looking to centralize the logic of printing over a number of separate applications instead of implementing printing for each application. The printing also utilizes a mapping which allows us to define for various reports in our SSRS which printer they should go to dynamically; therefore we thought to go this route. I feel like we are really close, I'm just not sure what's going wrong here.

Please let me know what you think, I will be very grateful.

Comment: If you haven't already, check your server's Event Log for any errors that may be getting logged for Acrobat or your web app.

Comment: Hey, unfortunately no errors thrown from acrobat. It is launched and just silently idles without printing. Our app has event logging setup too but to it everything seems good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through a great amount of reading and trial and error we found a solution for our situation: switching from leveraging Adobe Acrobat Reader for Foxit Reader. The main difference seems to be that Adobe Acrobat Reader requires a user profile to be loaded in order to work, while Foxit does not.

I'm posting this so that in case anyone comes across it in need they can see what worked for us. The code does work, it was the additional application we were leveraging that did not.